# How to pick up system location(region) on Chrome for an angular application?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript

I'm trying to figure out a way to pick up system location/region(e.g: en-GB, en-US) on to the angular application. 

I'm looking for an alternative for the below C# line of code.

```
 System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion
```

I know we can get the browser's current region (eg en-GB, en-US) using `navigator.language` but this won't help here since I want the system region.

Appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.navigator.language || window.navigator.userLanguage
```

Comment: This will return the browser region which is set under Languages in chrome settings. 
But I'm looking for a way to get the system's region, probably a way to get it from PC settings...

Comment: Only IE has this property inside navigator object
 navigator.systemLanguage // gets windows preferred locale
Other than that you should use server side language to access OS setting

Comment: yes. window.navigator.userLanguage and window.navigator.systemLanguage only work for IE but not for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use the system-locale package of npm

```
npm install system-locale
```

Usage

```
const locale = require('system-locale')
locale().then(console.log)
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/system-locale